# xarray.open_rasterio can't open more than ~400 files inside list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension, geospatial, python-xarray, rasterio

**What happened**:

when trying to open 14,000 files in a list comprehension with `xarray.open_rasterio`, the loop never completes. The goal is to open all these GeoTiff files, change the band dimension to a date dimension, stack by date, and save as a .single .nc.  It can open less than 400 files no problem within the list comprehension. This is the case on two different Linux machines.

But when I create the list ahead of time and instead use a regular for loop to open each file and append the result to the list, it finishes on all 14000 files in about a minute as intended. Why is there a performance difference/possible bug when using a list comprehension? Is there something I'm missing about python list comprehension performance in general?

Also, I used the linux command `lsof` to determine that pretty quickly in with the list comprehsension, about 446 files stayed open while the script never completed. The value fluctuated around 446 if I kept checking `lsof` (it lists files opened by a process with `lsof -p`). So it seems like some files weren't being closed in a normal amount of time.

**What you expected to happen**:
I thought it would take about a minute, since opening a single file takes about 41 milliseconds.

**Minimal Complete Verifiable Example**:
The data folder chirps-clipped can be downloaded here: https://ucsb.box.com/s/erqz20bgojhvpw2xpdbbcs17e131xxe4

```py
import xarray as xr
import rioxarray as rio
from pathlib import Path
from datetime import datetime
%matplotlib inline

all_scenes_f = Path('../rasters/chirps-clipped')

all_precip_paths = list(all_scenes_f.glob("*"))
# for some reason the fll value is not correct. this is the correct bad value to mask by
testf = all_precip_paths[0]
x = rio.open_rasterio(testf)
badvalue = np.unique(x.where(x != x._FillValue).sel(band=1))[0]

def chirps_path_date(path):
    _, _, year, month, day, _ = path.name.split(".")
    day = day.split("-")[0]
    return datetime(int(year), int(month), int(day))


def open_chirps(path):
    data_array = rio.open_rasterio(path) #chunks makes i lazyily executed
    data_array = data_array.sel(band=1).drop("band") # gets rid of old coordinate dimension since we need bands to have unique coord ids
    data_array["date"] = chirps_path_date(path) # makes a new coordinate
    return data_array.expand_dims({"date":1}) # makes this coordinate a dimension

### each data file is small and isn't tiled so it is not a good idea to use chunking
# https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/2314

import rasterio
with rasterio.open(testf) as src:
    print(src.profile)

%timeit rio.open_rasterio(testf)

### This is where the file opening bug happens
daily_chirps_arrs = [xr.open_rasterio(path) for path in all_precip_paths]
```

**Anything else we need to know?**:

**Environment**:

Output of xr.show_versions()

```
INSTALLED VERSIONS
------------------
commit: None
python: 3.8.5 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Sep 16 2020, 18:01:20) 
[GCC 7.5.0]
python-bits: 64
OS: Linux
OS-release: 5.4.0-53-generic
machine: x86_64
processor: x86_64
byteorder: little
LC_ALL: None
LANG: en_US.UTF-8
LOCALE: en_US.UTF-8
libhdf5: None
libnetcdf: None

xarray: 0.16.1
pandas: 1.1.4
numpy: 1.19.1
scipy: 1.5.2
netCDF4: None
pydap: None
h5netcdf: None
h5py: None
Nio: None
zarr: None
cftime: None
nc_time_axis: None
PseudoNetCDF: None
rasterio: 1.1.6
cfgrib: None
iris: None
bottleneck: None
dask: 2.27.0
distributed: 2.30.1
matplotlib: 3.3.2
cartopy: None
seaborn: None
numbagg: None
pint: None
setuptools: 49.6.0.post20200917
pip: 20.2.3
conda: None
pytest: None
IPython: 7.18.1
sphinx: None
```

Comment: I suspect you're hitting the system open file limit - try ulimit to see, the solution is to close the file after you make the change